# SSRS error - A scope is required for all aggregates Used outside of a data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm getting SSRS error - A scope is required for all aggregates Used outside of a data region unless the report contains exactly one data set.

I searched on google but still not figure out

```
= iif(((100/(DATEDIFF(MIN([initiative_Start_plan]),"InitiativeDatasettansiq"),
MAX([initiative_end_plan]),DAY))),"InitiativeDatasettansiq")
 *DATEDIFF(TODAY(),MIN([initiative_start_plan]),DAY)/100*-1)>1,1,
 (100/(DATEDIFF(MIN([initiative_start_plan]),"InitiativeDatasettansiq"),
 MAX([initiative_end_plan]),DAY)))
 *DATEDIFF(TODAY(),MIN([initiative_start_plan]),DAY)/100*-1), 
 "InitiativeDatasettansiq")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any one please ...............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your field references look incorrect. they should be something like

```
MIN(Fields!initiative_Start_plan.Value)
```

or

```
MIN(Fields!initiative_Start_plan.Value, "myDataSetOrGroupName")
```

The error is basically saying that you are using an expression outside of a data region and therefore you need to tell it where to get the data for each field from.

If this does not help then you'll need to show more info. You will need to show where your expression is going to be used so please show your report design including the names of datasets and/or row/column groups (if any).

Comment: still getting error its text box and i using exp in it

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and show report design, dataset names, row and group name as I said earlier. AT the moment there is not enough information to work with.

Comment: just add images

Comment: The first thing I see is that the Field name is incorrect. Field names are Case Sensitive so the first one should be `Fields!initiative_start_plan.Value` not `Fields!initiative_Start_plan.Value`

Comment: now getting tis error 

arumrnt not specified for parameter 'datevalue' of public function day(datevalue as date) as integer

Comment: This should really be a new question, Your original question has been answered. However, the syntax for `DATEDIFF` is `DATEDIFF(datepart, startdate, endate)` . See this reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/datediff-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017